# How I can define a new function as a function argument?

Tags: functions, packages, variable-definitions

I need to pass a function with t as independent variable as a function parameter and want to create a new function of the same through this provided the argument of another function. Here is my code.

```
f[t_] := t^2 + 5

Data2EWB[f[t], 0, 15, 10, "C:\Users\Jorge\Documents\desafio\aeste.txt"]

BeginPackage["Package`"];

Data2EWB::usage = 
  "Data2EWB(f_, tmin, tmáx, npts, “circelet.txt”) Salva \
   arquivo com nome desejado para função de Entrada"

Begin["Private`"];
Data2EWB[y_, tmin_, tmax_, npts_, dir_] := 
  Export[
   dir, 
   MatrixForm[Table[{t // N, funcaot[y, t] // N}, {t, tmin, tmax, (tmax - tmin)/npts}]]];
funcaot[y_, t_] := fc[y, t];
fc[y_, t_] := y;
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

I need to resolve the function that was passed as a parameter, to save data in the txt, but do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer or maybe just an extended comment.

Your expression

```
Data2EWB[f[t], 0, 15, 10, "C:\Users\Jorge\Documents\desafio\aeste.txt"]
```

has two problems. First, `f[t]` should just be `f`. Second, at least as it appears in your question "C:\Users\Jorge\Documents\desafio\aeste.txt" will give syntax errors.

I would suggest trying

```
Data2EWB[f, 0, 15, 10, 
  FileNameJoin[{"C:", "Users", "Jorge", "Documents", "desafio", "aeste.txt"}]]
```

Or, better, assuming that `C:\Users\Jorge\Documents\` is your documents directory

```
Data2EWB[f, 0, 15, 10, FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "desafio", "aeste.txt"}]]
```

I am not saying this will fix your code. But you need to deal with these very basic issues to go forward. I would further suggest you should get your code working at top-level before adding the complication of wrapping it in a package.